# What's difference between *var* and var when using defvar?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

In some docs,I found that they say the answer is `*var*` means global variable.

But when I try, I couldn't make sure that.

```
  FIRST-PACKAGE[27]> (defvar b 1)
  B
  FIRST-PACKAGE[28]> b
  1
  FIRST-PACKAGE[29]> (defun add_b (x) (+ x b))
  ADD_B
  FIRST-PACKAGE[30]> (add_b 3)
  4
  FIRST-PACKAGE[31]>
```

In my example, `b` is still not global if that answer is right.

But why the function `add_b` still can use it?

How to understand this example and `*var*`?

Thank you~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right. In Common Lisp there are effectively two types of variables: the ones you use all the time, which are lexically bound, and "special" variables, which are dynamically bound. "Special" variables are created with `defvar`, `defparameter`, or a declaration. The `*earmuffs*` are a convention that exists to remind Lisp programmers that a variable is special. Here are some examples:

```
(defvar b 3)

(defun add-to-b (x)
  (+ x b))

(add-to-b 1)
  => 4

(let ((b 4))
  (list (add-to-b 1) b))
=> (5 4)

(let ((a 3))
  (defun add-to-a (x)
    (+ x a)))

(add-to-a 1)
  => 4

(let ((a 4))
  (list (add-to-a 1) a))
=> (4 4)
```

As you can see, changing the value of a special variable in a `let` makes the value change "trickle down" to all of the function calls in that `let`, while value changes of a regular, lexically-bound variable don't get passed down, In fact, lexically bound variables are looked up by moving up the scopes that are located where the function wan *defined*, while special variables are looked up by moving up the scopes where the function was *called*. The `*earmuffs*` are useful to stop programmers from accidentally rebinding a special variable, because they make special variables look different.

Answer (score 2):

I'm talking about Common Lisp here:

`DEFVAR` declares a global variable and declares that it uses dynamic binding. It is a *special variable*. We use `*b*` with the asterisks around it as a convention to remind us that it is a *special variable* - that it uses dynamic binding. Any other name is fine. It is just a convention. In your example you use the name `b`. I would not recommend that. Follow the convention and name variables declared by `DEFVAR` as `*b*` instead. The same rule is useful for `DEFPARAMETER`.

What you mean with your example is unclear. Of course you can use a global variable inside a function.

Comment: I know dynamic binding in C++. What's dynamic binding in lisp? How similar they are? Thank you~

Comment: @sam I suspect "not very much". In Common Lisp, it's dynamic variable lookup versus static variable lookup. In C++, it's a vtable dispatch versus compile-time method determination.

Comment: @sam: dynamic binding is explained in many places. Lisp books do it. A simple Google search will bring a lot of hits...

Answer (score -1):

First off: in order to declare a "special" variable in Common Lisp, you have to introduce it via `defvar`:

```
(devar *variable* "initial value")
```

The "ear muffs" (`*`) around the variable name are merely a convention, which tells a human reader, that the variable is special. This has nothing to do with telling the compiler that the variable is special. Note, that the `*` characters are part of the variable's name (yes, Common Lisp allows `*` in symbol names -- together with a whole bunch of other "unusual" characters)

Comment: Actually, I think all you need is to declare it as special, then set its value.